# How to get ID property from Name property. angular observables rxjs

Tags: angular, database, rxjs, observable

I have a list of users in a select-option box.

It pulls the users from the database and shows their first names.

This component passes the value of this box (their name) as a string to a service.

But I want that person's ID as well.

I'm using:

```
this.UserService.userName = this.userForm.get('name')?.value;
```

How could I get about also getting the ID attached to that user?

Comment: Add datas response and more informations on the context code from the users service.

Comment: show code the populates the select list.  Seems like you would have the id at that point.

Answer (score 0):

A response without having datas could be:

```
let foundUser = users.find(user => user.name === this.UserService.userName);
```

With this mock example:

```
let users = [
    { id: 0, name: 'User 0', otherProp: '321' },
    { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: '648' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Another User', otherProp: '850' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Last User', otherProp: '984' }
];
```

A working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-id-property-from-name-property?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the way you are binding to the select box. While binding make sure you use the id as value, so that the `this.userForm.get('name')?.value` return the value you are expecting.

For ex.

if you want id to be as a value

```
 <mat-select formControlName="name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
```

Or if you want name and id both to value (not recommended)

```
 <mat-select formControlName="name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" value="{{user.id}}-{{user.name}}">{{user.name}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
```

And now when you do

```
this.UserService.userName = this.userForm.get('name')?.value;
```

Depending on the option you choose you will get the desired value.

I hope it helps.